# VBA - 1004 Error when using Advanced Filter

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I keep getting a 1004 error when running the advanced filter line below.

I am unsure why because the script runs fine when the LRI variable is replaced with a number equivalent to the value of the variable.

I included how I am setting the LRI variable. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 With Sheets("SheetName")
    LRI = .Range("A:A") _
        .Find(What:="*", _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
End With

With Sheets("SheetName")
         Range("A30:U62").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
            .Range("Q1:Q" & LRI), Unique:=False
 End With
```

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint in your code to confirm that `LRI` is truly equal to what you think it should be?

Comment: Nope. I just did it and saw I was being stupid and skipping over the part of the code I pasted that set LRI when I was running the script. Thanks.